# See reason why records failed to encrypt

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

I am going through an encryption effort in a SF sandbox. While encrypting, I noticed a few inconsistencies. For example, I got an email mentioning: Sandbox: Unable to Complete Encryption Task.  I am now seeing records showing up in the "Encrypted Records" section of the Encryption Statistics and Data Sync page.  Is there a way to tell WHY these failed to encrypt, and which records failed to encrypt?  I have been searching through and unable to find anything as of now.

Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen this, but I recommend you check if you're not using these fields in a way that encrypted fields cannot be used (for example, in a group by or a where clause of a SoQL statement)

Comment: The only reason why a value *should* fail to encrypt is if the value exceeds 175-characters. All other types of errors should be an all-or-none situation. Unfortunately, I think the only way you could find out more would be to contact support.

Comment: what type of fields are you trying to encrypt where you get that message?

Comment: @JohnWhelan There is a list of 5 field IDs included in the email.  They are all text fields.  I am assuming this email stems from the small amount of failures when each field was encrypted.

Comment: Support was able to hook me up.  They said we ran into "some known limitations" with the background job.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that you're running into a situation where the ciphertext is too long to fit in the text field.  In that case you'd get what you describe here, with IDs of the offending fields.

Check the length of text in those fields.

Alternatively - you can contact support and they can give you an exact reason.